# solution to make HTML template editable by client

Tags: content-management-system

I just bought a HTML template for a client of mine, it's a pure html template. I would like to find a tool to allow my client (which is non technical) to edit this template directly online.

Here's a bit of the html template I would like to let him edit:

```
<h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Site amet....</p>
```

Of course as my client is non technical, I'm thinking of a PHP tool where I could myself update the template like this:

```
<h1><?php editable('section1.title'); ?></h1>
<p><?php editable('section1.description'); ?></p>
```

Then my client will be able to access a web interface where he can update every key in this template as if it were translations (if you see what I mean).

I there a simple CMS allowing to convert html template into dynamic pages?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use jquery and assign an id to each html tag you want your client to be able to edit and then creating a reference .js file where the text can be input by your client.

Your html would become something like

```
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<p id="description"></p>
```

Your jquery would look like

```
var titleText = "Lorem Ipsum Dolor";
var descriptionText = "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Site amet....";

$("#title").text(titleText);
$("#description").text(descriptionText);
```

Then you just have him update the variables, which should be easier than having to traverse an html file.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In fact I already saw a tool doing this, and I'm looking for this exact same tool. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: no problem, you could also create a native javascript version using document.getElementById(idname) in lieu of $("#idname") to avoid required jquery references.